# android Scrolling Tabs

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I want to scroll tabs in android tab widget in my application, i used [this code](http://blog.uncommons.org/2011/04/18/scrolling-tabs-in-android/)
it works fine for android 2.2 but on android 4.0 it shows very big space like the figure bellow

[image]

this is my code 
((Horizontal

```
ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.tabWidget_sv))
                                            .post(new Runnable() {

                                                @Override
                                                public void run() {
                                                    // TODO Auto-generated
                                                    // method stub
                                                    ((HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.tabWidget_sv))
                                                            .fullScroll(View.FOCUS_RIGHT);
                                                }
                                            });
```

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's causing the tabs to not scroll on Android 4.0, but I think it's worth mentioning that in Android 4.0, TabActivity is deprecated and you are expected to use the Action Bar for tabs.  The Action Bar also has a built in behavior to scroll tabs for you when they start to go off screen.  The only downside is that you'll have to refactor your app to use Fragments, and you'll probably have to use the Android Support Libraries if you want to keep supporting Android 2.2.

You can go [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html) to learn more about the Action Bar.  If you want to use the Action Bar in older versions of Android (such as 2.2), I'd recommend looking into using  [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/)

Comment: Perhaps there is, but I'm not sure how to fix it.  Hopefully someone else will come along and give you a solution to your specific issue.  I just wanted to make sure that you were aware of the new Action Bar convention.  Sorry I couldn't be of more help!